# Python 3.4 PYSNMP Set issues

Tags: python, set, snmp, python-3.4, pysnmp

Python 3.4  -  Latest version of PYSNMP ( pip --update )

Having issues setting ifAlias values using PYSNMP library.  Hoping that someone might be able to shed light on why I'm getting errors in the second function.

Verified that this OID is setable using a standard MIB browser ( iReasoning )

This one works just fine. You just need to put a string `new sys contact value` in the function and it’s good.

```
def SNMP_SET_SYSCONTACT(syscontact):
            errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds =  cmdGen.setCmd(
cmdgen.CommunityData('private'),
cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('10.101.0.221', 161)),(cmdgen.MibVariable('.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0'), syscontact), 
lookupNames=False, 
lookupValues=True)
```

This one doesn’t work at all.

```
def SNMP_SET_IFALIAS(ifAlias):
                errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = cmdGen.setCmd(
cmdgen.CommunityData('private'),
cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('10.101.0.221', 161)),(cmdgen.MibVariable('1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.1'), ifAlias),
lookupValues=False, 
lookupNames=False)
```

The error I'm getting back is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#632>", line 1, in <module>
    SNMP_SET_IFALIAS('Check this out')
  File "<pyshell#629>", line 2, in SNMP_SET_IFALIAS
    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = cmdGen.setCmd(cmdgen.CommunityData('private'),cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('10.101.0.221', 161)),(cmdgen.MibVariable('1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.1'), ifAlias),lookupValues=False, lookupNames=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysnmp/entity/rfc3413/oneliner/cmdgen.py", line 452, in setCmd
    kwargs.get('contextName', null)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysnmp/entity/rfc3413/oneliner/cmdgen.py", line 314, in setCmd
    self.makeVarBinds(varBinds),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysnmp/entity/rfc3413/oneliner/cmdgen.py", line 212, in makeVarBinds
    varVal = varName.getMibNode().getSyntax().clone(varVal)
AttributeError: 'MibIdentifier' object has no attribute ‘getSyntax'
```

I'm happy to provide additional information if required.

---

Two more quick questions

**1)** I tried to grab the latest pysnmp 4.2.6.2 but I'm getting blocked on install with the following error

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyasn1>=0.1.8
>   (from pysnmp) (from versions: 0.0.9a0, 0.0.10a0, 0.0.11a0, 0.0.12a0,
>   0.0.13a0, 0.0.13b0, 0.0.13, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.4, 0.1.5, 0.1.6, 0.1.7)   No matching distribution found for pyasn1>=0.1.8 (from pysnmp)

**2)** Am I misunderstanding the lookupValues=False & lookupNames=False kwargs above? I thought that should have allowed me to access the OID directly without having to import the MIB.  I wanted to avoid any dependencies if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug in pysnmp -- latest CVS version might not throw that way.

However, the root cause of that error is that pysnmp could not find a MIB object corresponding the 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.1 OID. That may happen either because MIB that defines that OID is not loaded or OID in question does not correspond to any MIB object.

To load IF-MIB you may either do it explicitly:

```
cmdgen.MibVariable('1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.1').loadMibs('IF-MIB')
```

or use MIB::object.index syntax:

```
cmdgen.MibVariable('IF-MIB', 'ifAlias', 1)
```

You could grab the IF-MIB.py from pysnmp-mibs package available on pypi or compile it from ASN.1 MIB by [experimental] pysmi compiler (http://sf.net/projects/pysmi/)